# docker: get container's external IP

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

Running several docker containers including `postgres` database remotely.

```
$docker-compose ps
        Name                      Command                  State                                Ports
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fiware-cygnus          /cygnus-entrypoint.sh            Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:5050->5050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5080->5080/tcp
fiware-elasticsearch   /docker-entrypoint.sh elas ...   Up             9200/tcp, 9300/tcp
fiware-grafana         /run.sh                          Up             0.0.0.0:53153->3000/tcp
fiware-iotagent        pm2-runtime bin/lwm2mAgent ...   Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:4041->4041/tcp, 5684/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5684->5684/udp
fiware-memcached       docker-entrypoint.sh memca ...   Up             11211/tcp
fiware-mongo           docker-entrypoint.sh --bin ...   Up             0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp
fiware-nginx           nginx -g daemon off;             Up             0.0.0.0:53152->53152/tcp, 80/tcp
fiware-orion           /usr/bin/contextBroker -fg ...   Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:1026->1026/tcp
fiware-postgres        docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up             0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp
fiware-wirecloud       /docker-entrypoint.sh            Up (healthy)   8000/tcp
```

I want to get the external IP address of the `fiware-postgres` container so I can connect via pgAdmin, instead of managing db via `postgres` client. It appears the IPAddress of `fiware-postgres` is only accessible internally.

```
$docker inspect fiware-postgres | grep "IPAddress"
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPAddress": "172.19.0.3",
```

pgAdmin error:

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Operation timed out
Is the server running on host "172.19.0.3" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Is there a way to get it's external IP, or at least some way of connecting via pgAdmin (remember docker container run on a remote, accessed via `ssh`).

**EDIT**

The remote host is accessible via `ssh root@193.136.x.x:2222` so the `postgres port 5432` cannot be reached.

pgAdmin settings(Connection Tab):

```
Host: 193.136.xx.xx
Port: 5432
Maintenance database: postgres
Username: postgres
Password: password
```

pgAdmin error:

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Operation timed out
Is the server running on host "193.136.x.x" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

`postgres` service definition (in `docker-compose`):

```
postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:10
    hostname: postgres
    container_name: fiware-postgres
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - default
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password"
      - "POSTGRES_USER=postgres"
      - "POSTGRES_DB=postgres"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    build:
      context: .
      shm_size: '2gb'
```

Comment: You should be able to connect using the local host `127.0.0.1: 5432` or the server ip address. `172.19.0.3` is the internal docker dns ip address

Comment: @Varcorb question edited to add issue detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that works for me:

```
ssh -p 2222 root@193.136.xx.xx -L 5432:localhost:5432
```

`postgres` server finally accessible via pgAdmin

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you have [exposed the ports of your container to the underlying host](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports), then the application is accessible via the IP address of the underlying host.

The `172.19.0.3` IP address is an IP address that exists inside the Docker network on the host: it's not available externally.  If your remote host has IP `1.2.3.4` and your application port has been exposed, e.g. in your compose file you have something like:

```
ports:
  - "5432:5432"
```

Then your application should be accessible via `1.2.3.4:5432`.

EDIT:

If you are connecting from your local machine to the remote server using pgAdmin, then there should be no need to ssh: you should find that the service is still available at `1.2.3.4:5432`.  However, if you have some form of firewall in the way (e.g. you're sshing in to an AWS server), then access to `5432` on the remote host may well be blocked.  In that case, consider using [port forwarding](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example) to route connections on your local server to the remote server, via the ssh connection.

```
ssh -L 5432:193.136.x.x:5432 193.136.x.x:2222
```

Now connect using pgAdmin to `localhost:5432` or `127.0.0.1:5432`.

Comment: I can confirm the port 5432 is exposed in the `docker-compose` file. However, the remote host is accessed on port 2222 i.e `ssh root@193.136.x.x:2222`  so port 5432 cannot be reached.

Comment: Your application is available without needing to ssh: it's on `193.136.x.x:5432`.  If you ssh into the remote host and you're inside a shell, it's still available at that IP and port.

Comment: Question edited to add details to the issue. I think I am doing exactly what you're saying.

Comment: On what port is the service exposed?  Do you have `"5432:5432"`, or just `"5432"`? Also, from what host are you running pgAdmin? Is it the host you are sshing from, or are you running it on the remote host?

Comment: port is exposed as shown in `postgres` service definition (Question Edit) above.

Comment: From what host are you running pgAdmin? Is it the host you are sshing from, or are you running it on the remote host?

Comment: pgAdmin runs on my local machine, not on `193.136.x.x` remote host.

Comment: See revised solution.